# WSO2 EMM : Name & Model field error for Android

Tags: wso2-iot

WSO2 is not properly configured for retrieving information about the model and name.
It's just reversed for Android.

The error is that WSO2 EMM retrieves this information from the Android build.prop file located in the / system folder.

Currently:

- For the name, it retrieves the field: ro.product.device
- For the model, it retrieves the field: ro.product.brand and ro.product.model

Here is what it takes to make the fields correct

- For the name: ro.product.brand and ro.product.model
- For the model: ro.product.device

[Look this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pGfY.png)

How can this problem be corrected so that the WSO2 EMM information gives the information in the right place?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

You can interchange line [1] & [2] and rebuild the android agent.

[1] - https://github.com/wso2/product-emm/blob/master/modules/mobile-agents/android/client/client/src/main/java/org/wso2/emm/agent/api/DeviceInfo.java#L73

[2] - https://github.com/wso2/product-emm/blob/master/modules/mobile-agents/android/client/client/src/main/java/org/wso2/emm/agent/api/DeviceInfo.java#L125